# Are preprocessor directives allowed in a function-like macro's argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

This question regards the legality of using a preprocessor directive within a function-like macro's argument.

Consider the following code. `#ifdef` is used inside `MY_MACRO`'s argument :

```
#include <iostream>

// Macro to print a message along with the line number the macro appears at
#define MY_MACRO( msg ) { std::cerr << "Line " << __LINE__ << "\t- "<< msg << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    // Print the current build configuration
    MY_MACRO(
#ifdef NDEBUG // <-- preprocessor directive in macro argument
        "Release"
#else
        "Debug"
#endif
    )
}
```

gcc 12 is fine with it, msvc 19 does not allow it : https://godbolt.org/z/G8j4aTG6j

What does the standard have to say about it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/967162/can-i-use-ifdef-in-a-macro-which-uses-to-form-a-st.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No

[[cpp.replace.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.replace#general-13):

> The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most matching parentheses forms the list of arguments for the function-like macro. The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate arguments. **If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is indeed, both the question and the answer is better.